# How to use Material UI (mui) 5.0 inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, material-ui, emotion

I'm trying to render MUI components inside an iframe using react portal. Although they are rendered inside the iframe, they lose all thMUI components lose their styling when rendered inside a iframe using react portals. All the documentation/examples and discourse on this topic is related to older versions of MUI. This is even worse when working with ShadowDOM.

[image: Button and Typography components inside an iframe]

[image: No styles related to MUI]

Comment: Their injected styles are all injected to the root document's <head> but not the iframe's head. Not sure if they provide some configurations to manage this.

Answer (score 2):

MUI is using emotion as a styling engine by default, and @emotion has a CacheProvider to config where you want to place the styles.

```
const PreviewIframe = styled('iframe')(() => ({
    border: 'none',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
}))
const PreviewPortal = (props: PreviewPortalProps) => {
    const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState<any>(null)
    const mountNode = contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body
    const cache = createCache({
        key: 'css',
        container: contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.head,
        prepend: true
    })
    return (
        <PreviewIframe ref={setContentRef}>
            {mountNode &&
                ReactDOM.createPortal(
                    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
                        {props.children}
                    </CacheProvider>,
                    mountNode
                )}
        </PreviewIframe>
    )
}
```

Look these links for more details.
https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/#npm
https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/cache#container